# How can I convert .htaccess code to web.config?

Tags: apache, iis

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://%2%3 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host} ([^.]+).itsprofile.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://itsprofile.com/viewindex.php$1?id =%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your question? What are you trying to achieve. You can't just dump a lump of code down and hope that we're going to fix your problems for you...

Comment: Yeah buddy, I've been trying to do this for more than 3 hours now. I have no idea how to convert it. I saw some 'tutorials' but they require IIS for the conversion. Thought there could be some guys who could help me out with this. I don't ask anyone to do this for me. Some suggestions will do. I'm blank right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say convert to web.config, I'm going to assume you mean convert .htaccess rewrite rules to IIS URL Rewrite rules.  You can find information about importing .htaccess rules to IIS URL Rewrite [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules).

Your rewrite rules above would be imported and converted to this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".?" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="(on)?" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www.)(.+)$" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http(?{C:1}s)://{C:2}{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_Host}" pattern="([^.]+).itsprofile.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://itsprofile.com/viewindex.php{R:1}?id" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Naturally, you'll want to test all of your rules.